# Find nearest div with class disableDiv and disable all of its contents

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this code I am checking the chekbox with class disableDivCheckbox and the code is disabling all of the div content with class disableDiv. But if I apply this combination to another checkbox and another div, this is not working properly. So I want to find closest div with class disableDiv and disable only that div. I am using disabale * because I want to disbale div and its contents.

```
$(".disableDivCheckbox").click(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
               $('.disableDiv *').removeAttr("disabled");
            }
            else {
                $('.disableDiv *').val('').prop('checked', false).attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
        });
```

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/8c0x1pho/

Comment: Show the HTML. Is `disableDivCheckbox` child of `disableDiv`?

Comment: 2 options: `.closest(...)` or `.parents('commonParent').find(...)`. Which one to use will depend on your markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this approach:

- Get checked state and save it in a variable
- Navigate to all necessary elements using `this`. It will make your code more modular.
- Try not to use `*` selector. Use more specific selectors as this will specify element types you are manipulating and make your code more reusable.
- Instead of `attr` and `removeAttr`, you can just set value of `disabled` as `true` or `false` . You can just use `!$(..).is(":checked")`

**Sample:**

```js
// Only call functions. DON'T declare any functions in ready.
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Have a common function. 
  // If size grows, this can be exported to its own file
  registerEvents();
  
  // Initialise on load states.
  updateUIStates("#addBusinessObjectivesCheckbox")
});

function registerEvents() {
  $(".disableDivCheckbox").click(function() {
    updateUIStates(this)
  })
}

function updateUIStates(el) {
  var isNotChecked = !$(el).is(":checked");
  var inputs = $(el)
    .parents(".checkbox")
    .siblings(".disableDiv")
    .find('input');
  inputs.attr("disabled", isNotChecked)
  isNotChecked && inputs.val('').prop('checked', false)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset id="AddBusinessObjectivesFieldset" class="">
  <legend>
    Add business objectives
  </legend>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="addBusinessObjectivesCheckbox" name="addBusinessObjectivesCheckbox" class="disableDivCheckbox" id="addBusinessObjectivesCheckbox"> Add business objectives
    </label>
  </div>
  <div style="border: 2px solid;margin-bottom: 5px;border-color: gray;padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px;margin-top: 5px;margin-right: 10px;" class="disableDiv">
    <div class="form-inline" style="margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="radio">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="AddBusinessObjectives" id="" value="0" class=""> Fixed N
              </label>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="radio">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="AddBusinessObjectives" id="" value="1" class=""> Random upto N
              </label>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Enter N" id="indexTextboxAddBusinessObjectives" name="indexTextboxAddBusinessObjectives" style="width:70px" class="" />
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

#### Pointers

- `$(document).ready()` is more like `init` function. Try to call functions instead of defining in it. This will make easier to understand as it will depict a flow.
- Use pure functions and call then. Like `onChange`, you can call few functions: `updateUIStates()`, `postDataToServer()`, `processResponse()`, `otherTodos()`. This may look like overkill but in long run this will help.
- Create a tree structure in your markup.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="checkbox-container">...</div>
  <div class="input-containers">...</div>
</div>
```

This will ease navigation part. No matter what structure you use, keep it standardised. This will keep your JS clean.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$(".disableDivCheckbox").click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).closest('.disableDiv *').removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
        $(this).closest('.disableDiv *').val('').prop('checked', false).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});
```

This means that, you will disable all content of only that disableDiv class to which disableDivCheckbox belongs.

Give it a try, this will work.

Comment: I would not suggest anything before knowing HTML structure. Answering with half knowledge can go against you.

Comment: I believe, if requirement is clear regardless of html, css, js or whatever, still you can answer.

Comment: @Rajesh is giving wise suggestion listen to him, any way above code will not work. I am leaving it for you to identify

Comment: Okay, thanks mate !  I will keep this to me from next time @Rajesh

Comment: @ParagBandewar I have rolled back your edit. Please run your code and then paste links. You were missing jQuery in fiddle. People would have checked fiddle for working demo and when things don't work, they would just assume its users code and would downvote it.

Comment: @Satpal Thanks for backing me up. :-)